# Istio Inject Delay VirtualService

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, istio

My architecture is simple. Services: `web > datastore`.

All I want to do is inject a 5s delay into any requests going to the datastore, so I've created a `VirtualService` to do this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: datastore-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - datastore
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        percentage:
          value: 1
        fixedDelay: 5s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: datastore
```

Some other info if it helps:

```
kubectl get services
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
datastore        ClusterIP   10.106.54.111    <none>        27017/TCP   23h
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP     2d18h
web              ClusterIP   10.106.162.190   <none>        3000/TCP    23h
```

---

## YAML Files

**web-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: adamgardnerdt/customnode
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

**web-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web
  name: web
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3000"
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: web
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**datastore-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: datastore
  name: datastore
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: datastore
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: adamgardnerdt/custommongo
        name: datastore
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

**datastore-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: datastore
  name: datastore
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "27017"
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: datastore
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**Ingress Gateway and VirtualService**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: quotations-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: quotations-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - quotations-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web
        port:
          number: 3000
```

## Edit

My `web` service is a nodeJS based web server.
I've tried this with an `httpd` server and the delay works fine.
Therefore it's something to do with the async nature of node.

My confusion grows. Regardless of the async nature of nodeJS, the page is only rendered to the user within the `renderPage()` function. So...

1) `db.collection('quotes').find().toArray((error, quotes))` is executed.

2) Istio sees the call going from `web` to `datastore` and delays it for `X` seconds.

3) The call succeeds and finally `renderPage` is called.

4) The page is rendered (with DB content) after the Istio-induced delay.

What's *actually* happening is that the page (with DB content) is rendering immediately. I don't know how / why this is happening...

---

Code for my `web` image:

```
const express = require('express');
const filesystem = require('fs');
const app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var MongoURL = "mongodb://datastore:27017/";

var defaultQuotes = [{ "author": "no quotes", "content": "No content. Is MongoDB down?"}];

function renderPage(error, quotes, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/index.ejs', { quotes: quotes });
}

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Attempt a connection to MongoDB
  MongoClient.connect(MongoURL, function(err, client) {
    console.log('connected to MongoDB');
    try {
      var db = client.db('quotesDB');
      // Get all quotes and then call the renderPage function.
    db.collection('quotes').find().toArray((error, quotes) => renderPage(error, quotes, res));

    // Close the connection to Mongo
    client.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log('exception caught');
      renderPage(null, defaultQuotes, res);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Delay is not happening? Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: How r u testing and verifying the delay?

Comment: By hitting http://127.0.0.1/ ? The page and MongoDB results return immediately.
Those docker images are public so you should be able to recreate

Comment: You mean all requests from outside the cluster that goes to the web should be delayed by 5s?

Comment: Actually I want to inject the delay for calls between `web` and `datastore`.
I don't have subsets or `DestinationRule`s defined. Perhaps these are mandatory?
All the demos I can find online is routing *within* a single service. Surely I can toggle between two services!?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i checked in istio

> fault:
>                      description: Fault injection policy to apply on HTTP traffic at the client side.

So like provided in istio documentation [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/) You can add delay when calling web, but i couldn't find a way to make it work to work between web and datastore since it's tcp connection and I couldn't find anything about that in documentation, only the http one.

So if You want delay calling your website here is the yaml for that

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: quotations-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - quotations-gateway
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        fixedDelay: 5s
        percentage:
          value: 100
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web
        port:
          number: 3000
```

There is something in above link called "hard-coded connection timeout"

> reviews:v2 service has a 10s hard-coded connection timeout for calls to the ratings service

Maybe that's the thing you're looking for, so You would have actually change this in deployment side, not istio.

I hope it will help You. Let me know if You have any more questions.